# Implementing nested layout using Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement recursive layout using Bootstrap 3 but width of cell are reducing every time I put it in a container/row.

```
<h4>Example 1:</h4>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">[SIDEBAR]</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Cell Outer</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Cell Outer</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Cell Outer</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Cell Outer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h4>Example 2:</h4>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                [SIDEBAR]
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">Cell In</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/firozansari/jXt69/3/

In example 1, "Cell Outer" has proper widths but in example 2, "Cell In" widths are reduced because of parent row.

I am trying to implement layout which is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try the updated html?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">SIDEBAR</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">CELL</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with col-xs-3 but it misaligned with section with col-xs-2 cells. I uploaded a mockup layout to explain my requirement.